# Optional String added to output - Swift

Tags: json, swift, option-type

Been working on pulling data from an API, finally got that to work (I believe correctly) but when I print out variables within the dictionary, "Optional" gets added to the string

```
        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            print(jsonResult)
            if (jsonResult != nil) {
                if let players = jsonResult?["players"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                    for player in players {
                        let personID = player["name"]
                        print(personID)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("No Data")
                // couldn't load JSON, look at error
            }
        }
```

Sample of the JSON Output:(note I cut this down and used only the first element)

```
Optional({
players =     (
            {
        name = "Derek Anderson";
    },
```

Print statement:

```
Optional(Derek Anderson)
```

My assumption here is that its printing the Optional Dictionary and then grabbing the "players" name. Meaning I haven't pulled just that name out. I've pulled the name out of the players array, not the Optional.

I feel like I may be adding that Optional Array in some way though, cant seem to figure this one out!

Comment: If you sure you have data for your name, you can try `print(personID!)`

Comment: See my answer below, should have tried one more thing before posting! Hopefully this helps someone out

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the variable needs to be unwrapped:

```
        do {
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
        print(jsonResult)
        if (jsonResult != nil) {
            if let players = jsonResult?["players"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                for player in players {
                    let personID = player["name"]!
                    print(personID)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("No Data")
            // couldn't load JSON, look at error
        }
    }
```

Comment: Forced unwrapping is not the best choice, as it can easily led to crashes, especially if you're dealing with server data. Better use an `if-let`.